# Make div stick to percentage of screen size

Tags: html, css

I am working on my own personal website, its is currently live so you can view it and can probably even see what im trying to solve.

Website -> http://www.warrenbreedlove.com

What im trying to do is make the right half of the web page responsive in a way. The bar on the left i need to always stay that size but the social media links and the portfolio page i want it to kinda scale depending on what size monitor you viewing it on.

I figure it would be easiest to check it with firebug or inspect

If i change the .container to 80% rather that 940px it seems to work somewhat on a larger wider monitor but then breaks on my laptop screen

```
.container { 
    position: relative; 
    width: 940px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;    
    float: left;
    padding-left: 45px;

}
```

I would like the portfolio area to scale as well, right now if the size gets too small it will just send it all under neath the left bar. (If the screen size gets smaller the number of images displayed should slowly decrease to like maybe 1 or two before it breaks)

Im not sure really what other code to post in here that would effect the width the categories/social media and the portfolio part.

This filters part is only for the categories

```
 #filters {
   margin: ;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
   border-bottom: solid 1px #dad8d6;
   width: 920px;
   padding-top: 5px;
 }
```

thank you!

Comment: Avoid using fixed width as much as possible when creating a responsive website. Frameworks like Bootstrap can you help you achieve responsiveness

Answer (score 1):

Like other people have said don't use fixed width values use percentages instead.
And I also believe Bootstrap is NOT the answer, I think people should only use Bootstrap once they have mastered CSS to make development faster!

So instead to make your website responsive:

Add this meta tag to your `<head>`, this will make mobile devices scale your screen properly

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Add this to your `global css`, this will make percentage based element resize with padding more intuitively.

```
html {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after { /* Inherit box-sizing to make it easier to change the property for components that leverage other behavior; see http://css-tricks.com/inheriting-box-sizing-probably-slightly-better-best-practice/ */
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
            box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

The rest is just playing about with floats and positioning and percentages till you get something that works!

Here is what I did to get your layout to work:

I made your `#sidebar` position fixed, so it would still work nicely with scrollbars, and the rest was just adding a few percentage values (or removing fixed width values).

```
#sidebar {
    width: 270px;
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #959595;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 286px;
}

#filters {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #dad8d6;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I tried these changes you mentioned but it doesnt seem to work properly. It fixes it a bit as it gets scaled down fut it doesnt really do anything when the screen size is a larger screen, nothing seems to be "responsive" kinda just stays the same untill it breaks.

Comment: I checked it again, and appears 'responsive' to me. Did you remove your old styling or combine yours and mine?

Answer (score 0):

Responsiveness can also be made possible with meta tags that adjust to the viewport. Additionally, setting width:100% makes the pixel/fixed value issue go away. You might need to manipulate with margins, but Bootstraps might also be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you get started.

Change your css to this:

```css
#filters {
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 270px;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
}
```

change all container widths to auto in media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Better not using fixed width or height when you want to achieve responsiveness. Percentage is a nice way. And there is an another tip that 20%+80% is NOT equal to 100%. If you set the property of two `inline-block` elements with the widths 20% and 80%, it will break. A solution is that one is 20% and the other is 78%.(Here, `margin` and `padding` are not into consideration.) Actually, responsive design is a big issue and a field worth paying attention to. Bootstrap has provided us with fantastic solutions. You can refer to it. And, good luck.

Comment: Plus: media query is a strong tool. Try it!